# How do I check spelling of a user input?

Tags: javascript

I'm creating a website where the user types whatever he hears in an audio file. On submit, I want to compare his input to the actual paragraph and then display the misspelled words. How can I do that?

Comment: Do you have a correct transcript of the audio file already, or do you need a speech-to-text sort of thing? Also note that library recommendations are off-topic here.

Comment: No, I have the transcript already. I just need to let the user know which words did he spell incorrectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// answerParagraph is the true answer (string)
// inputParagraph is the input from the user (string)
let mistakes = 0;
let mistakedWords = [];
for(let i = 0; i < answerParagraph.length; i++){
  if(answerParagraph[i] != inputParagraph[i]){
    mistakes++
    mistakedWords.push(answerParagraph[i])
  }
}
alert("You have " + mistakes + " typos!")
```

I think this should work. :)

Edit: Well if you want to check every word one by one instead of the whole paragraph then the code is:

```
// answerParagraph is the true answer (string)
// inputParagraph is the input from the user (string)
let mistakes = 0;
let answerWords = answerParagraph.split(" ")
let inputWords = inputParagraph.split(" ")
for(let i = 0; i < answerWords.length; i++){
  if(answerWords[i] != inputWords[i]){
    mistakes++
  }
}
alert("You have mistakes in " + mistakes + " words!")
```